# Is there a way to replace a function during compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, makefile

Say I have a large number of .c files where some of them use the function `foo()`. This function is not defined within these files.

While I leave those code intact for the .c files, when I compile them as executables, I want all those files to call `bar()` instead of calling `foo()`. Is there a way to make that happen through the Makefile?

Comment: It's possible, but this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/142198), so you might want to also explain your motivation for wanting to do this, in case there's a better overall solution.

Comment: `.c` is C, not C++.

Comment: As well as the solution in the linked file, there's the obvious, "add `int foo() { return bar(); }`" solution.

Comment: @PaulR The main reason is that the number of files is too large to edit each of them.

Answer (score 0):

C has a thing called a `preprocessor`. It's used to do things at compile time (if we want to be pedantic, it actually runs before the compiler).

For example, `#include <stdio.h>` tells the preprocessor to include the stdio.h file.

You can recognize that a line is addressed to the preprocessor via the `#` symbol.

Here's a more elaborate example, that is relevant to your question:

```
void foo() { ... }
void bar() { ... }

#ifdef USE_BAR
#define foo bar
#endif

foo();
```

If you `#define USE_BAR`, any time you call foo, it will call bar instead. You can define USE_BAR in your makefile.

Note that using macros can cause code readability and maintainability issues.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't do anything at compile time, it does it *before* the actual compilation.